# Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app(). React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, native

I have been learning react native from two weeks. Now I try to learn how use firebase with react native. I follow a tutorial video in which we display our firebase data in app. I follow full tutorial and write code same as it in tutorial. But i got this Error i dont know what is the reason of it i installed almost every module that we need. But problem not solved.

My code is here :-

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

export default function App(){
  function readFunction(){
    const onValueChange = database()
      .ref('Main/mama')
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        console.log('User Data:', snapshot.val());
        setMama(snapshot.val());
      });
  }
  const [name, setMama] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    readFunction()
  }, []);

  return(
    <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'space-around'}}>
      <Text>
        Mama = {name}
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

And error is -

Comment: What version of React Native are you using?

Comment: I am using react native 1.0.0